# Indicator progress not showing in below from ios 13 after adding scene delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview

When calling MKProgress indicator from iOS 13 it's not showing, the below version works fine < 13 ios version.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
  MKProgress.show()
}
```

This happenes after adding SceneDelegate to project.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is all about third party library issue so please try

```
pod update
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your pod file with the below code

```
pod 'MKProgress', '~> 1.1.0'
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you provide some more information?

Comment: no error just its not display from ios 13 below its works fine.

Comment: this happenes after added sceneDeleagate to project.